# Error when starting scrapy project

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

Any time i try `scrapy crawl [name]` I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2793, in <module>
working_set.require(__requires__)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 673, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Scrapy==0.24.5
```

I'm not sure what it is I'm missing, I've tried following suggestions from other similar questions but nothing is working! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out. For some reason the `pip install Scrapy` was not completely installing so I downloaded the tarball from the website and then followed the instructions [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.12/intro/install.html) and it now works!